# Printing the lines after matching text

Tags: python, printing, find, match

I am trying to print the line that is after text matched in the text file.

Something like this:

```py
import re  

afterlines=3
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip()== ls_losses:
            row  = f.readline(+afterlines) 
            print (row)
            print ("true")
```

Comment: What is in your file?
Can you provide expected output and input for same?

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Please include your actual problem in the question. Do you get an error? Does the program behave differently from what you expected?

Comment: @PySaad Input can be: "Line1 Line2 Line3 Line4" , whereas ls_losses = Line1, and I need an output to be   say "Line3" or "Line4"

Comment: @eike The problem is I dont know what the script that is doing what I am asking for should look like.

Comment: But you already have code here. What is wrong with it? Do you get an error message? Is the output wrong? You only describe what you want to achieve, but not what went wrong when you tried.

Comment: @eike The expression: "row  = f.readline(+afterlines) " is not valid. It is not right syntax to put an argument "(+afterlines)" in the ".readline".

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a temporary counter.

```
import re  
afterlines=3
temporary_lines = ''

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() == ls_losses:
            counter = afterlines
            if counter > 0:
                temporary_lines += f.readline()
                counter -= 1
            else:
                print(temporary_lines)
                temporary_lines = '' # Reinitialize to get ready for the next match
                print ("true")
```

Comment: shouldnt the second "if" contain the line print(temporary_lines)? It does not work anyway.